# printable keyboard shortcuts

Tags: interface

Is there a good printable keyboard shortcut sheet (that looks like a keyboard) for Blender 2.75? I found a really nice one here: [Blender 2.4 Hotkeys](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Reference/Hotkeys/Map), but that was created for version 2.4 in 2005... and 10 years is a long time to not update key bindings/interface. Is it still good or is there a nice, printable (aka won't kill an entire ink cartridge) version somewhere else? A Google search doesn't really give me anything above 2.6 or that's economically printable.

Comment: while I have attempted to give some form of response below, the question borders on off topic for blender.stackexchange or should maybe be addressed in the [Resources for Blender thread](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15355/resources-for-blender)

Comment: Not exactly printable, but you might be interested in this [interactive one](http://waldobronchart.github.io/ShortcutMapper/#Blender).  It may be more convenient given the context sensitive nature of blender's shortcuts. There is an also an [addon in contrib](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/BAC/browse/master/system_keyboard_svg.py) which can auto generate SVG representations of the current keymap.

Answer (score 4):

is https://wiki.blender.org/uploads/1/14/Keyboardlayout_250.png no good printed in greyscale / low quality?

[image: here]

Alternatively tufts has a nicely compiled (but incomplete) list of shortcuts per area:   http://ocw.tufts.edu/data/71/1717950.pdf

The tufts shortcuts might be handier as it doesn't try to cram all info onto a few keys which change depending on mode anyway. Unfortunately it doesn't list some of the more useful key combos ( vertex-slide <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>)

Answer (score 0):

shortcuts (hotkey) & Charts for Blender

https://www.katsbits.com/tutorials/blender/useful-keyboard-shortcuts.php